# How to insert an HTML image if src contains a query string

Tags: html

In HTML, I can insert an image from URL using the img tag and src attribute.

```
<img src="apple.jpg" />
```

But if my src contains a query string, then the browser displays a little broken image icon rather than the desired image.  For example

```
<img src="http://fruitphotos.com/?type=apple" />
```

wouldn't work, even when that query returned an image file.

How can I insert image files returned from such queries?

Comment: Not an ad or unresearched question.  Have really struggled with this because I thought it was an HTML issue.  I think what is happening is that the server (not the silly example server in the post, but the real server I'm working with) is returning the image file wrapped in a bare bones html document -- just enough to derail the HTML img tag.  Looks like only an image in the browser.  Apologies for any confusion in the question.

Comment: You could try using an iframe to display the content instead (if it's returning an HTML document). It does look like this is a problem with the server and not your code.
It's also possible that your browser or adblocker is stopping your site from displaying images from another domain name.